# I want to flip a HTML/CSS Animation upside down

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have copied this [codepen](https://codepen.io/goodkatz/pen/LYPGxQz?editors=1000) and would like to flip the waves on the x-axis having them upside down on the top of my page.

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  color: black;
}

.inner-header {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  /*Flexbox for containers*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.waves {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  margin-bottom: -7px;
  /*Fix for safari gap*/
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 20vh;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}


/* Animation */

.parallax>use {
  animation: move-forever 25s cubic-bezier(.55, .5, .45, .5) infinite;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-duration: 7s;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -3s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-duration: 13s;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
  animation-duration: 20s;
}

@keyframes move-forever {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(85px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Sharif Atassi Portfolio</title>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="inner-header flex">
            <h1>Sharif Atassi</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <svg class="waves" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 24 150 28" preserveAspectRatio="none" shape-rendering="auto">
                <defs>
                    <path id="gentle-wave" d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z" />
                </defs>
                <g class="parallax">
                    <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="0" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.7" />
                    <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="3" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" />
                    <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="5" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)" />
                    <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="7" fill="#fff" />
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</head>
```

Comment: `style="transform: scaleY(-1)"` on the element you want to flip along the x axis

Comment: Note that a continuous animation like this can take up quite a bit of processor time. On a system with a reasonably high powered GPU it is taking up around 20%. On a lower powered phone for example it might be a bit of a battery-flattener.

Comment: It's as well to consider accessibility issues when introducing motion to your website. "Consider providing a mechanism for pausing or disabling animation, as well as using the Reduced Motion Media Query to create a complimentary experience for users who have expressed a preference for no animated experiences." see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: @AHaworth is there anything I can do to decrease, or help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here is my approach:

- Your content is positioned in the center of your header with grid layout
- Your waves are absolutely positioned at the top of the screen

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

header:not(svg) {
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  max-width: max-content;
}

.waves {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* Animation */

.parallax>use {
  animation: move-forever 25s cubic-bezier(.55, .5, .45, .5) infinite;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-duration: 7s;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -3s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-duration: 13s;
}

.parallax>use:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
  animation-duration: 20s;
}

@keyframes move-forever {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(85px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Sharif Atassi</h1>
  <svg class="waves" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 24 150 28" preserveAspectRatio="none" shape-rendering="auto">
    <defs>
      <path id="gentle-wave" d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z" />
    </defs>
    <g class="parallax">
      <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="0" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.7" />
      <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="3" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" />
      <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="5" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)" />
      <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="7" fill="#fff" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</header>
```